# jersey integration with spring

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I want to use Jersey 1.1 with spring 2.5. The exact thing that i need to do is write a interface which would be exposed as the service and implementation in a class that extends the interface.

I cannot do it in applicationContext.xml, maybe because the XSD has changed.

Could some one provide with a sample code/snippet/file where they have been able to implement this successfully.

Thanks in Advance,
Adhir Aima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it finally.. the new schema does support the basic bean definitions so the interface and the implementation classes can be specified using the old technique

```
<bean id="myService" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
<property name="proxyInterfaces">
    <value>com.poc.service.MyServiceInterface</value>
</property>
<property name="target" ref="myServiceimpl" />
```